# Implement a 'default' flag that can only be set on a single row in a given table

Tags: database, oracle, row, default

How to implement a 'default' flag that can only be set on a single row in a given table? at database level and what could be it's datatype in Oracle.

Or would it need to set up such a condition in the application, but not at database level?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a unique function-based index, something like:

```
create unique index uniq_default on your_table
  (case when default_flag = 'Y' then 'Y' else null end);
```

Null values aren't indexed, so the case statement evaluates to either a single value or null; and because it's unique yhe single value can only appear once.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22e6b8/2) showing an error trying to insert a second row with the flag set to Y. Same thing happens if you [try to update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22e6b8/3) a value to Y to create a duplicate.

Or you could use a virtual column with the same logic and a unique constraint, which is much the same thing.